# How do I test this ASP.NET MVC code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to get the following code under test.  What do I need to mock out in order to get this working considering it is not running as part of a web request?  The current exception I am getting is "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage"

```
public void Handle(HttpContextBase ctx)
{
    RequestContext rc = ((MvcHandler)ctx.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
    IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    IController controller = factory.CreateController(rc, "home");
    var cc = new ControllerContext (rc, (ControllerBase)controller);
}
```

Please any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Could the issue be that you're asking for the RequestContext before there's a request?  That's what the exception text sounds like to me.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? You don't seem to be doing anything with the `cc` variable. Did you forgot to show your real code?

Comment: @dan-ryan, did you figure this on out? I'm having the same problem.